# How to make asterisk server automatically response to SIP call?

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, phone-call, pbx

My objective: I want to use softphone(3CX phone) register with asterisk server, and make call to the server and asterisk act

as a server to automatically response something, like play a song.

How i did: I installed asteriskNow using virtualbox, and registered the softphone by setting exntension for my SIP device

(extension 333). And i write a dialplan in *etc/asterisk/extensions.conf*. The dialplan is :

```
[incoming]
exten =>s,1,Answer()
exten =>s,n,Playback(dir-intro-oper)
exten =>s,n,Hangup()
```

I want any incoming call to server, the server will automatically answer, and play a pre-defined voice (dir-intro-oper.gsm )

then handup.

But I met the problem is:

I use softphone, and i dont know which number i should dial to the asterisk server. Should i set up a extension number for

asterisk server itself? If so, how to do that? By setting up SIP truck? Write the dialplan in sip.conf? or anything else?

Another questions:
I read the asterisk related book"asterisk, the future telephony" which tells us to write dialplan in the extensions.conf

directly, but i found the extensions.conf in the server which alerts us do not modified the file directly, must use web-gui

to modify.So which way i should follow?

In this case, i do not use any other hardware phone.
I am a novice on asterisk, please give me some hints and detail procedure.

Comment: If you are using AstriskNow, you are supposed to use the built-in freepbx web interface to manage all your dialplans and settings etc. see http://www.asterisk.org/asterisknow/quickstart

Comment: Hi, If you want to custom your dialplan, i think you should overwrite the extensions.conf I did not find where to modify in the freepbx webgui. And this problem seems to be solved like that: i modified the extensions_custom.conf file with following code:   [from-internal-custom]    
exten => 1234,1,Playback(dir-intro-oper)  ; extensions can dial 1234
exten => 1234,2,Hangup()
exten=>h,1,Hangup()

Comment: Make sure the context name is [from-internal-custom] , and do not modifed the context name. And it works. I use 3cx phone dial '1234' and the server automatically response with my pre-defined voice files(dir-intro-oper.gsm).

Answer (score 1):

The "s" extension that you are using is a "special" that when Asterisk doesn't know what to do, it tries to use that.

If you really want any call to the box, either from a VoIP phone or an ITSP to get handled the same way, try this:

```
[incoming]
exten =>_X.,1,Answer()
same => n,Playback(dir-intro-oper)
same => n,Hangup()
```

... and make sure that in your SIP phone and SIP trunk definitions that you set:

```
context=incoming
```

That literally forces all calls into your context and then no matter what you dial, you always match the extension number.

More reading at https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

Answer (score -2):

```
[incoming1]

exten => 333,1,Answer()
same  => n,Playback(File_name)
same  => n,Hangup()
```

Go to /etc/asterisk/extension_custom.conf and write your context like this:

and name the context as incoming1 or anything else cause incoming context already exists. I have named it as incoming1:

[image]

Now goto /etc/asterisk/sip_additional.conf and edit the context of extension you are going to register on the softphone.

[image]

Now register the softphone and you can dial the number 333 and everything will work properly.

![][3]