# Linux console SIP client

Tags: sip, daemon

For my purposes I am searching sip client which will be auto answer on calls. It must be multithread for parallel calls. It must work as daemon. 
Is exists that SIP client?

Comment: Asterisk server can be configured to do exactly this.

Comment: Can you provide example configuration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12834423/2702398

Answer (score 0):

You need an IVR based Solutions something like VOIP PBX Systems. Some open source choices are 
FreePBX http://www.freepbx.org

Or FusionPBX http://www.fusionpbx.com